# PHP MySQL REGEX match search

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I want to fetch data from my user table which tag id stored like :

```
userid  tagid 
5036    |4815|324|                
1396    |1393|4567|                   
2676    |2669|345|2345|
```

I have a tagid array like as
Array
(
    [0] => 4815
    [1] => 4567
)

Need to fetch data using mysql where in condition like `"select * from user where tagid in ()"`.
Is there any preg_match function for it?

Comment: Can you just do where tagid like '%|4815|%' ? Of course that's not efficient but it's the way the table is designed.

Comment: but the problem is i have array of tagids and to do search with that array.

Comment: Loop the array and append the values to the where.

Comment: The problem is that your tables are not normalized.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad for why your tagid column is going to cause you sorrow and pain until you create a separate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you loop the array and append using likes, something like:

```
   $tags = array(2,4,6);
   $query = 'select * from user where ';
   foreach($tags as $i=>$tag) {
       if ($i>0) $query.=' or ';  // or and?
       $query.='tagid like "%|'.$tag.'|%"';
   }
```

Comment: This works as long as their own array isn't indexed with something else. Cool concatenation though.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're having to use a wildcard on both sides of the match they would both be about the same (I think regexp may be a little faster in your case).

The problem is that you may have false positives because of the chance of a substring in your searches because of the lack of normalization.

An example:

```
Searching for %15%

Matches 915,15,150,215790
```

Because of this, you should actually do this, since in this case, LIKE would not be sufficient unless you always wrap the IDs in the pipe characters `|`:

```
<?php
    $ids = array('115','215','225');

    foreach($ids as $id){

      $query = "select * from user where tagid regexp '[^0-9]*$id[^0-9]*'";

    }

?>
```

At which point you could use this:

```
<?php
    $ids = array('115','215','225');

    foreach($ids as $id){

      $query = "select * from user where tagid like '%|$id|%'";

    }

?>
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte as long as they stick to their non-standard convention of surrounding the IDs with pipe characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
$tagid = array(4815,4567);
$query = "select * from user where tagid regexp '\|("
       . implode("|", $tagid) . ")\|'";
```

then you obtain:

```
select * from user where tagid regexp '\|(4812|4567)\|'
```